# Derivative of a cost function (Andrew NG machine learning course)

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, machine-learning

I'm currently doing Andrew's course, and in this course there's a part that he shows the partial derivative of the function $\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x^i)-y^i)^2$ for both $\Theta_0$ and $\Theta_1$. But I couldn`t wrap my mind around it. I would like to see a step by step derivation of the function for both $\Theta$s.

The Hypothesis Function is defined as $H_\Theta=\Theta_0+\Theta_1x$

And the partial derivatives are

**For $\Theta_0$**

$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x^i)-y^i$

**For $\Theta_1$**

$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x^i)-y^i)x^i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider I have a function $u = x^2 +1$ and $f(x)=u^2=(x^2+1)^2$. Following [chain rule](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-differentiation-2-new/ab-3-1a/v/chain-rule-introduction), I will get the derivative:

$\frac{df}{dx}= \frac{df}{du} * \frac{du}{dx}= 2(x^2+1) * 2x$

Do the same with machine learning problem, call $f = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x^i)-y^i)^2$, just focus on $u = H_\Theta(x^i)-y^i$, we can see that:

$\frac{df}{du} = 2*(H_\Theta(x^i)-y^i)$

With $\Theta_0$: $\frac{du}{dx} = 1$

With $\Theta_1$: $\frac{du}{dx} = x^i$

Number $2$ is shortened with $2m$ equal $m$

Comment: Notice that in the equation $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$, the same symbol $f$ is used to refer to two different functions. I think this can be a source of confusion.

Comment: you mean I should change the bottom $f$ to be $f(\Theta)$,right?

Comment: Let $u:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by $u(x) = x^2 + 1$, and let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by by $f(s) = s^2$. The function $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $F(x) = f(u(x))$ is not the same function as $f$, so it deserves to have its own name. According to the chain rule, $F'(x) = f'(u(x)) u'(x)$. The chain rule is often stated as $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} \frac{ du}{dx}$, but I think this is an abuse of notation because on the left we are taking the derivative of $F$, not $f$.

Comment: okay, very clear comment. Thanks for lighting me.

Answer (score 1):

It's just chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{d\Theta_0} \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x_i)-y_i)^2 $$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d}{d\Theta_0}(H_\Theta(x_i)-y_i)^2 $$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d}{d\Theta_0}(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i)^2$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}*2*(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i) * \frac{d}{d\Theta_0}(\Theta_0+\Theta_1*x_i-y_i)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}*2*(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i) * (1)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}*2*(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i) = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x_i)-y_i)$$
And for $\Theta_1$:
$$\frac{d}{d\Theta_1} \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x_i)-y_i)^2 $$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d}{d\Theta_1}(H_\Theta(x_i)-y_i)^2 $$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d}{d\Theta_1}(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i)^2$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}*2*(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i) * \frac{d}{d\Theta_1}(\Theta_0+\Theta_1*x_i-y_i)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}*2*(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i) * (x_i)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2m}*2*(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i)x_i$$
$$ = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\Theta_0+\Theta_1x_i-y_i)x_i = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(H_\Theta(x_i)-y_i)x_i$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit inelegant to compute partial derivatives directly. The cleanest way to do this calculation, in my opinion, is to write the objective function as
$$
L(\Theta) = \frac{1}{2m} \| X \Theta - Y \|^2
$$
where
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 \\ 1 & x_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_m \end{bmatrix},
\qquad Y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_m \end{bmatrix}, \qquad \Theta = \begin{bmatrix} \Theta_0 \\ \Theta_1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Notice that $L(\Theta) = g(h(\Theta))$, where
$$h(\Theta) = X \Theta - Y, \qquad g(u) = \frac{1}{2m} \| u \|^2.
$$
The derivatives of $h$ and $g$ are
$$
h'(\Theta) = X, \qquad g'(u) = \frac{1}{m}u^T.
$$
By the multivariable chain rule,
\begin{align}
L'(\Theta) &= g'(h(\Theta)) h'(\Theta) \\
&= \frac{1}{m}(X \Theta - Y)^T X.
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
\tag{1} \nabla L(\Theta) = L'(\Theta)^T = \frac{1}{m}X^T ( X \Theta - Y).
$$

---

Here's another approach which  has the virtue that it is quite similar to the gradient calculation required for logistic regression. 
Let $h_i:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by
$$
h_i(u) = \frac12 (u - y_i)^2.
$$
So $h_i'(u) = u - y_i$.
Notice that
$$
L(\Theta) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m h_i(\hat x_i^T \Theta).
$$
By the multivariable chain rule, the derivative of $L$ is
\begin{align}
L'(\Theta) &= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m h_i'(\hat x_i^T \Theta) \hat x_i^T \\
&= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (\hat x_i^T \Theta - y_i) \hat x_i^T.
\end{align}
Thus, 
$$
\nabla L(\Theta) = L'(\Theta)^T = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \hat x_i(\hat x_i^T \Theta - y_i).
$$
This is equivalent to the expression (1) above.